# How can I crop to square with Django Easy Thumbnails?

Tags: django, easy-thumbnails

I'm using easy-thumbnails all over my site. It works fine generally.
But now I'd want to create a product feed for Facebook and the pictures need to be 600x600px square.

It looks like this:

```
thumbnailer = get_thumbnailer(v.product.image)
thumbnail_options = {
  'crop': '50,0', #tried smart, scale and all kinds of combos
  'size': (600, 600)
}
resized_image = thumbnailer.get_thumbnail(thumbnail_options)
```

The problem is that I always end up getting one dimension to 600px, and the other to <600px.
Can I make it do something like the smart option but cropping in a way that I get a square image?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think the parameter was `upscale`

Comment: Indeed! This was it. Thanks Lauri!
I've changed crop to 'smart' and added 'upscale': True

Answer (score 1):

```
thumbnailer = get_thumbnailer(v.product.image)
thumbnail_options = {
  'crop': 'smart',
  'upscale': True,
  'size': (600, 600)
}
resized_image = thumbnailer.get_thumbnail(thumbnail_options)
```